# How can I make a div visible after I've hidden it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to make my image and text disappear and appear onclick. While it will disappear, once I've hidden it I can't make it visible again. How can I fix this?

My Javascript:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.visibility == 'visible')
    e.style.visibility = 'hidden'
else
    e.style.visibility = 'visible'
}
```

And inside my html template:

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"/>
    <div id="foo" style="visibility:visible;" >
        <img src="../static/image1.png"   
            style="left:17%;position:fixed;">
        <div class="scrollBox" 
            style="font:12px;height:30%;width:55%;left:17%;position:fixed;overflow:auto;"/>
            <p> text and stuff goes in here </p>
```

Comment: Why don't you have `;`-s at the end of your statements?

Comment: Not required in javascript @xxbbcc http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: @PatrickMurphy I know. The question still stands. I mean, one could use `goto`.

Comment: @PatrickMurphy not disagreeing with you. :) The question was relevant, though. :)

Comment: @Courtney, Lance's answer is correct. The essence of the problem is twofold:  1) your HTML is malformed, and (relatedly) 2) there is nothing besides your `#foo` diff to click on. Once you hide it, what are you expecting the `onclick` event to respond to?! Anoop's answer also works, but does not actually explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need the ;'s

Also, you need something to click.  Your a tag was malformed.

```js
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.visibility == 'visible')
    e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
else
    e.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click Me</a>
    <div id="foo" style="visibility:visible;" >
        <img src="../static/image1.png"   
            style="left:17%;position:fixed;">
        <div class="scrollBox" 
            style="font:12px;height:30%;width:55%;left:17%;position:fixed;overflow:auto;"/>
            <p> text and stuff goes in here </p>
```

Comment: Also, an `href` attribute is necessary to give the element actionable stying

Comment: @Ankit No it doesn't. The OP's a tag ends with /> which terminates the tag, which therefore does not contain anything.

Comment: Aside from not fixing the poor indentation in the OP's javascript, this is the best answer. Why the downvotes?

Comment: @Ankit your link is completely irrelevant to this. If `/>` doesn't terminate the tag, then the OP is clearly missing an `</a>` because something needs to terminate it... which is why everyone who is trying to be helpful fixed the broken HTML rather than defending it.

Comment: Please read the question. The problem was not that the "disappearing" did not work. The problem was that it would not reappear (because there is nothing to click on, because of malformed HTML)

Comment: ...Which is because of bad HTML.  How does that escape you?

Comment: @Lance i don't know who flagged and who on Earth deleted my whole comments but your answer is simply not answering the question, the OP wanted the anchor to disappear and reappear like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52vth38m/). You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52vth38m/1/) that the problem is because of missing closing `div` tag not because of self closing `a` tag(which is also wrong but not the cause of the problem) as you can see it not working with correct `a` tag but missing `div` tag.So the answer is that the OP is missing closing div tag

Comment: @Ankit Did you happen to notice your jsfiddle doesn't work either?  The problem is with the A tag because, once hidden, there is nothing to click to make the content reappear.  I flagged your posts as not constructive because they were wrong.  They were then reviewed by the moderators and removed.  It may help you to step back and review the post and code in a new, unbiased light and you will see that the A tag is the problem.

Comment: @Lance which browser are you using, I checked the link on chrome and mozilla both and is working fine you click it disappears then you click again at the very same place and it reappears.

Comment: I've tested this in IE and Chrome.  It doesn't even work when I DO close the div tags.  Think about it.  There simply has to be something to click.

Comment: @Lance `The problem is with the A tag because, once hidden, there is nothing to click to make the content reappear`. Really, `visibility:hidden` only dissappears the element but the element still stays in the layout(unlike `display:none`) ,it catches mouse events, so I think your whole point in answering the question was wrong.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work in Chrome for me either.  I am fine to agree to disagree with you and just let it go.  We have nothing to gain by continuing this conversation.

Comment: @Lance You sure you checked [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52vth38m/) because this link has all the proper tags( so you don't have to touch the code just test it) except `a` and working fine. It's not about letting go , it's about clearing the concept whoever is wrong so we don't commit the same mistake in future

Comment: @Lance i have even created a working video for you to see that it is working with self closing `a`(again mentioning which is wrong but not the cause) tag https://vid.me/Hrs5

Comment: Thank you for the effort but it was unnecessary.  For an answer to be good, it has to work all the time on the common browsers, not just randomly on one browser.  For what it's worth, I was able to get your version to work intermittently on Chrome.  It still doesn't work on IE though, so clearly isn't the right answer.  Again, you need to step back and look at it fresh.  I feel you are too wrapped up in "winning" at the cost of being right.  Have a nice day.

Comment: @Lance that is firefox( don't call it random) and I can make a demo for chrome too.And about IE , it has its own issues with block elements inside A tag. For IE after replacing div and p with span it works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52vth38m/2/) but still it has self closing a tag so your answer is not correct. Again it's not about winning , it's about correcting a mate.

Answer (score 0):

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zenotzr6/)

Your Html code is not correct

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"> test
    <div id="foo" style="visibility:visible;">
        <img src="../static/image1.png"   
        style="left:17%;position:fixed;"/>
        <div class="scrollBox" 
            style="font:12px;height:30%;width:55%;left:17%;position:fixed;overflow:auto;">
            <p> text and stuff goes in here </p>
        </div>

        </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Also, an `href` attribute is necessary to give the element actionable styling

Comment: @Ankit Because the asker had an anchor tag that did not enclose anything clickable.

Comment: @Ankit There *is* no element inside the `a` tag in the original question. It ends on line #1!! In any case why are you advocating usage of poor/invalid HTML, even if it happens to be acceptable to your favorite browser?

Comment: @Ankit Sheesh. I did just run this HTML, verbatim, in Firefox 38--with the original, semicolon-less javacript no less. It works fine. It even works with the original malformed `a` tag--of course, in that case it ignores the `/>` and makes the rest of the entire document part of the unclosed `a` tag. Add an `href="#"` and a `</a>` at the end of the first line and it even looks reasonable.